# Creating a Custom File Upload CoreProperty Field?

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, file-upload, custom-field-types, user-profile-property

I'm currently working on a site where the client has requested a "Resume" field where they can upload a Word Document of the person's Resume.

So far, I have created the `CoreProperty` field: "Resume" that has `PropertyDataType.URL` as its type. I'm stuck on where I should go from here. After doing some research, I've found that one of the approaches is to create a custom page for editing profiles and have a file upload field be displayed for that.

I'm thinking I should be able to create a new type of `CoreProperty` where I can define a `DelegateControl` for generating the HTML to upload the file.

So basically my question is what is the "SharePoint way" of doing something like this? Or is what I'm trying to do outside the scope of what SharePoint has to offer?

For what it's worth, here is the `CreateResumeField` function I have inside the event receiver for my custom feature:

```
private void CreateResumeField(SPSite site, SPServiceContext context, UserProfileConfigManager upcm)
{
    ProfilePropertyManager ppm = upcm.ProfilePropertyManager;

    // Create Resume property.
    CorePropertyManager cpm = ppm.GetCoreProperties();
    CoreProperty resume = cpm.Create(false);
    resume.Name = "Resume";
    resume.DisplayName = "Resume";
    resume.Type = PropertyDataType.URL;
    resume.Length = 255;
    cpm.Add(resume);

    // Create profile type property for the resume.
    ProfileTypePropertyManager ptpm = ppm.GetProfileTypeProperties(ProfileType.User);
    ProfileTypeProperty ptp = ptpm.Create(resume);
    ptpm.Add(ptp);

    // Create profile subtype property for the resume.
    ProfileSubtypeManager psm = ProfileSubtypeManager.Get(context);
    ProfileSubtype ps = psm.GetProfileSubtype(ProfileSubtypeManager.GetDefaultProfileName(ProfileType.User));
    ProfileSubtypePropertyManager pspm = ps.Properties;
    ProfileSubtypeProperty psp = pspm.Create(ptp);
    psp.PrivacyPolicy = PrivacyPolicy.OptIn;
    psp.DefaultPrivacy = Privacy.Organization;
    psp.IsUserEditable = true;
    pspm.Add(psp);
}
```

Comment: Check out how the User Profile picture field is implemented, it uses a URL field that points to other SharePoint resources.

Answer (score 1):

Try working the opposite way arround.

Let them upload their resume as document in a document library. Create a content type with all the needed information that they need to fill out.

Make sure that the users can only view their own entries/uploads.